# How to format currency for Brazilian Real in PHPExcel

Tags: format, phpexcel, currency

I am trying to format currency for Brazilian Real but can't get to a valid mask.

The value 10.00 should be masked to 10,00
The value 1000.00 should be masked to 1.000,00

I have tried the code:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($cell)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
    '#0.##0,00'
);
```

But the value 10.00 is making to 1000.00.

Comment: Format as `#0,##0.00` and let MS Excel handle the locale presentation

Comment: I had my Mac Locale set to English US, I changed it to Brazilian Portuguese and it worked like a charm. However, I think a mask should work as a mask besides locales. But, this is a specific characteristic of Excel... as I am not an excel expert I treated masks as any others application developments treats.

Comment: The mask internally in the files is `#0,##0.00` and it's only the MS Excel GUI that handles localisation... PHPEXcel doesn't know your locale, and isn't a GUI app, so it can't know how to interpret a mask like `'#0.##0,00'`

Answer (score 0):

try setFormatCode('R$ * 0.00');

Comment: You should post an explanation for your coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($cell)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
    '#,##0.00'
);"
```